# C# Pass boolean as bit for sql_variant parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to use C# to execute [`sp_set_session_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql) whose 2nd parameter, `@value`, is of type sql_variant. But there doesn't seem to be a way for me to indicate that the value I'm providing for @value is a bit. Here's the code:

```
DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "sp_set_session_context";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@key";
param.Value = "key";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@value";
param.Value = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The code above executes this:

```
exec sp_set_session_context @key=N'key',@value=1
```

Since `@value` is sql_invariant, it treats the 1 as an int instead of a bit. What I need is:

```
exec sp_set_session_context @key=N'key',@value=cast(1 as bit)
```

Is there anyway to do this other than executing SQL text rather than calling the stored procedure directly?

Comment: when you execute it passing `1 or 0` does it work.. it would fail if you passed 2 digits vs a single digit, bits are On or Off True or false which is (1 or 0) not sure what the issue is..

Comment: No. If I pass 1 or 0, the `param`'s `DbType` changes to `Int32` instead of `Boolean` but it results in the same SQL which treats it as an int. The problem is SQL has no way of knowing I want `1` to be a bit and not an int.

Comment: declare your parameter type as `System.Data.DbType.Boolean` then and if value == 1 then true else false

Comment: in your code you can do this for example `bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(1);` this returns `true` `bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(0);` this returns `false` so you could do this before you assign the param 
`bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(yourIntValue);` then pass `b` to the `sp_set_session_context`

Comment: That reduces down to the same thing I posted in the question above: `param.Value == true`

Comment: you must have something else going on.. can you show the sql on the server side..?

Comment: It's included in the question. sp_set_session_context is a built in procedure. Its documentation is linked to in the question.

Comment: doesn't look like you are executing based on the example from the documentation..